# Haskell: can't understand the bottleneck

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I solved a Project Euler problem and then confronted my solution with the one on the Haskell wiki. They were pretty similar, but mine was taking 7.5 seconds, while the other 0.6! I compiled them both.

Mine looks as follows:

```
main = print . maximumBy (compare `on` cycleLength) $ [1..999]
        where cycleLength d = remainders d 10 []
```

and the one of the wiki:

```
main = print . fst $ maximumBy (comparing snd) [(n, cycleLength n) | n <- [1..999]]
        where cycleLength d = remainders d 10 []
```

I also tried to change `` compare `on` `` with `comparing cycleLength` but the performance remained the same.
So I must conclude that all the difference lays in computing values on the fly vs. doing the transformation in the list comprehension.

The difference in time is pretty huge though: the second version has 12.5x speedup!

Comment: This is an instance of the [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)

Comment: *"BTW it's not possible to escape backticks in inline code expressions?"* It is, if you use `<code>` instead of backticks.

Comment: @luqui: That's very interesting, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @rubik You can also use triple backticks, although you have to add a space at the end: ```compare `on` ```. If you want to make it look exactly like the `<code>` version you can use a zero-width unicode space character (`u+200b`): ```compare `on`​```.  They are particularly useful when you want to render a backslash at the end: ```\``` (triple backtick + one backslash + triple backtick) is simpler to type than `<code>\\</code>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `maximumBy` function will repeatedly check the same number in your list multiple times — and every time it checks a number, it will have to *re-compute* `cycleLength`. And that's an expensive operation!

The wiki algorithm thus uses a technique known as decorate-sort-undecorate. Now, here you're not sorting, but it's close enough. You first precompute the `cycleLength` values for all numbers, (i.e. you make a 'cache') *then* you do the maximum operation, and *then* you undecorate them (using `fst`.) That way, you save yourself a lot of computing!

EDIT: to illustrate it, have a look at the `maximumBy` function in the `Data.List` source:

```
-- | The 'maximumBy' function takes a comparison function and a list
-- and returns the greatest element of the list by the comparison function.
-- The list must be finite and non-empty.
maximumBy               :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
maximumBy _ []          =  error "List.maximumBy: empty list"
maximumBy cmp xs        =  foldl1 maxBy xs
                        where
                           maxBy x y = case cmp x y of
                                      GT -> x
                                      _  -> y
```

It moves in a window of 2; every number is requested (and in your case computed) *twice*.
This means that for 999 iterations, your version will call `cycleLength d` 1996 times (n*2-2), whereas the wiki version would call it 999 (n) times.

This doesn't explain the full delay — only a factor of 2, but the factor was closer to about 10.

Here's the profile of your version,

`COST CENTRE          entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
MAIN                        0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF                        0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
  main                      1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
   f                        1    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
    maximumBy               1    0.0    0.0   100.0   99.9
     maximumBy.maxBy      998    0.0    0.1   100.0   99.9
      cycleLength        1996    0.1    0.2   100.0   99.8
       remainders      581323   99.3   94.4    99.9   99.7
        remainders.r'  581294    0.7    5.2     0.7    5.2`

and the wiki version:

`COST CENTRE         entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc
MAIN                       0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 CAF                       0    0.0    0.0   100.0   99.9
  main                     1    0.0    0.1   100.0   99.9
   f'                      1    0.0    0.8   100.0   99.8
    cycleLength          999    0.2    0.5   100.0   98.6
     remainders        95845   98.3   93.0    99.8   98.2
      remainders.r'    95817    1.5    5.2     1.5    5.2
    maximumBy              1    0.0    0.1     0.0    0.4
     maximumBy.maxBy     998    0.0    0.2     0.0    0.2`

Looking at the profile here, it seems that your version goes through a lot more allocations (around 10-12 times as many,) but doesn't use a lot more RAM overall. So we need to explain about a cumulative factor of 5 or 6 in terms of allocations.

Remainders is recursive. In your example, it gets called 581294 times. In the wiki example, it gets called 95817 times. There's our 5-6 fold increase!

So I think the `compare` call here is also a problem. Since it applies `cycleLength` to both things we want to compare as well! In the wiki problem, `cycleLength` gets applied to every number, but here, we have it applied to every number twice, *and* the comparison seems to be applied more often, and that is a problem especially with the bigger numbers, since `remainders` has a bad complexity (it seems exponential, but I'm not sure.)

Since the maximum memory consumption of both programs isn't that dramatically different, I don't think this has anything to do with the heap.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this thorough analysis! Now I see what's going on.